# No rule error in ns2.35 simulator

Tags: ns2

i made some change on the mac-802_11.cc and mac-802_11.h  files in ns2 and when i type make command  in the terminal i got this error (make: *** No rule to make target 'diffserv/dsred.o,needed by  'ns'.stop 
Please could any one help.